# Installing custom Gym environment

Tags: python-3.x, openai-gym

I'm trying to install a custom gym environment that I created, but when I try to install it with the command line pip install -e, I get the following error.

```
Usage:
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

-e option requires 1 argument.
```

Can someone suggest a way to install the gym environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [doc](https://retro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Pip install expects either a path to download code from the python package index (PyPI) or the path to a local package.
For more details please checkout: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/ayx7za/how_does_pip_install_e_work_is_there_a_specific/

So to install the gym environment first cd into the directory of your gym environment and run:

```
pip intall -e .
```

from there. The '.' is the argument to pip install and represents the directory you are currently in.